# Is constructor of react class called only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one class saying NewVersionPopUp (called when click on Add Button) it has its own constructor. 
I have another class ApplicationView and it has its own constructor. Both the 
classes are in the same file. Now in ApplicationView I have one method onClose 
which will get called when i will click on close button of that popup (modal). On closing 
I want to set some variable(s) as false which are defined in NewVersionPopUp class constructor. 
onClose i am doing

```
this.setState({
  nameValid: false,
  descValid: false,
  fileValid: false
});
```

On console i'm getting error as nameValid is undefined. Because nameValid, descValid, fileValid are 
not defined in the same class where onClose is declared. So, how to pass this variable of NewVersionPopUp to ApplicationView 
class, so that i can use onClose function. And also is constructor of class is loaded only once? Its not getting called each time 
when i click on Add on button.

```
class ApplicationView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        message: 'welcome'
    };
  onClosePopup () {
    this.setState({
            address: '',
            nameValid: false,
            descValid: false
        });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={toggleChildMenu.bind(this)}>
          Toggle Menu from Parent
        </button>
        <NewVersionPopUp onClose={this.onClosePopup}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}



class NewVersionPopUp extends React.Component {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        nameValid: false,
        descValid: false
    };

    validateForm() {
        // check if name and description is valid and then set nameValid, descValid => true
    }
    render() {
        return (<div><button onClick={() => onSubmit}>Push me</button></div>
        <div><button isDisabled={!nameValid && !descValid} onClick={() => onClose}>Close</button></div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: show the 2 components here ...

Answer (score 0):

The constructor for a component is called before it is mounted in DOM. What you need to do here:

- Make a parent to these components
- pass props to the child / sibling (depends if your logic is being written in parent component)

So you can easily access these props inside `ApplicationView`. You just need to make a relation between your component as they are not in the tree.